# How many Ants in "The Ants Go Marching One By One" song

Tags: sequences-and-series

My 12 year old worked hopelessly to solve this, and I have done the same.

In the song 'The Ants Go Marching One By One Hurrah, Hurrah'. What are the minimum number of ants that must be marching such that:

1. The ants always march in a perfect ranks of 'w' wide by 'd' deep
2. When an ant leaves at the end of each round of the song, the ants
   can then reform to again a perfect rank of w x d without remainders?

For example,

1. Round 1: At the start of the song the ants go marching 1 x 1 , that
   is single file. So we have 1xd ants. Then at the end of the round
   one ant leaves to 'suck his thumb'. We now have n=n-1 ants
2. Round 2:
   The ants now go marching 2x2 that is w = 2, with some depth. But
   they must be in pairs without a remainder. Then 'the little one
   stops to tie his shoe' and so n=n-1
3. Round 3: The ants go marching 3x3, that is w=3 but they must be a perfect triplet without a
   reminder
4. etc to round 10

How many ants at minimum must we begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the system of congruences:
$$x-(i-1)\equiv 0\pmod i$$

where $1 \le i\le 10$.

This can be transformed to:
$$x\equiv -1\pmod i$$

By Chinese Remainder Theorem:
$$x \equiv -1 \pmod {\operatorname{lcm}\{1,2,\dots,10\}}$$

and $\operatorname{lcm}\{1,2,\dots,10\}=2520$.

Hence the smallest number satisfying the above is $2519$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut If the OP does not know how to compute lcm, they probably do not know much about congruences. In that case a lengthy explanation awaits.

Comment: Hi, I'm the OP, been 20 years since my B.Engineering degree, but yes I now recall congruences - and the method of the least common multiples. The solution now looks easy once you guys pointed it out! Greatly appreciated

Comment: @JimbobTheSailor Glad we could be of help.

Comment: Wait. $n=n-1$ at each step, right? So $2$ divides $n-1$, $3$ divides $n-2$, etc.?

Comment: ? Therefore $n+1$ divides all $1$ to $10$.

Comment: Wow, this one-line explanation is much simpler

Comment: Yes :o) ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: yes we can simply say find the number where $1$ divides $n-1$, $2$ divides $n-2$, 3 divides $n-3$ and so on... it has to be the LCM of numbers.